counterexample for non- monotone curvature function on the Kazdan-Warner identity
Let $\mathbb{S}^n\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be the unit standard sphere, $n\geq 2$. $K(\xi)=\xi_{n+1}+2$, where $\xi=(\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_{n+1})\in \mathbb{S}^n$. It is easy to see that $K(\xi)$ is strictly monotone in the $\xi_{n+1}$ direction, can we construct a function $K'$ defined on $\mathbb{S}^n$ such that  $K'$ is arbitarily close to $K$ in $C^1$-topology, but $K'$ is not strictly monotone in any direction? This problem concenrs with the sovablity of Nirenberg problem and the Kazdan-Warner identity. If such example constructed successfully, then it ansewers that the $C^1$ perturbation fails in the curvature function.
